# Как перевести файл в байт массив?

Tags: android, файлы, bluetooth, arduino, sd

Необходимо передать файл с SD карты Android на SD карту, подключенную к Arduino по средством Bluetooth.

Передача символа/строки и прием их со стороны Arduino есть. Но я не могу понять как разбить файл на байты, чтобы тем же способом отправить их.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

получить массив байтов можно так

```
InputStream is = Context.openFileInput(someFileName);
ByteArrayOutputStream bos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
byte[] b = new byte[4096];
while ((int bytesRead = is.read(b)) != -1) {
   bos.write(b, 0, bytesRead);
}
byte[] bytes = bos.toByteArray();
```

Также можно поизучать стримы, в сокете блютуз соединения тоже есть поток output, может будет лучше писать байты прямо в него, без промежуточного массива (https://stackoverflow.com/a/5333971/2190250)